# The minutes of the Stockholders Meeting "was" or "were"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

What is the correct verb

> The minutes of the Stockholders Meeting **was** presented and discussed

or

> The minutes of the Stockholders Meeting **were** presented and discussed

Should it be *was* or *were*?

Comment: 'Minutes' in this sense is a fairly rare example of a non-count noun [usage] (you can't speak of '3 minutes' in this sense) which takes plural agreement. Compare trousers etc, spectacles (glasses), pliers etc in some regions, police, cattle, and contrast clothing and furniture in the usual usage. Learner's Dictionaries unhelpfully label 'minutes' (of a meeting) 'plural'. It's not; it's non-count, of plural form, and taking plural agreement. Like 'trousers'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It all depends on whether the OP means "Minutes of the Stockholders Meeting" as one noun, or if they meant "the minutes of the stockholders' meeting". More clarification is needed

Comment: @Hank You can't say 'The last 3 minutes of the SM were destroyed in a fire' any more than you can say 'All my 7 trousers have gone missing'.

Comment: @Hank "All my 7 trousers has gone missing", "All my 7 trousers have gone missing" ... in fact "All my 7 trousers ... anything" are **all** wrong. 'Trousers' is always non-count and doesn't accept the '7' etc. And 'minutes' behaves the same way when referring to the notes taken at formal meetings; you can't have "7 minutes" in this sense. //  The trousers / minutes of the meeting / police / cattle ... **were** ... (not _was_) is correct, though many non-count nouns take singular agreement. "Headquarters" can be followed by either a singular or a plural verb-form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, so we at least agree there. My original point was, if the OP is referring to "Minutes of the Stockholders Meeting" as a proper name of sort, like the title of a report, regardless of whether it's being done incorrectly, then it would be *was*. This is because minutes is no longer the subject but, instead, a single proper noun is, the title of the report or work. I only bring that up because the OP shows those terms capitalized.

Comment: @Hank Without quotes or italics, that's a perverse reading. Though OP is not perfect. / I've edited to focus on what is almost certainly the point intended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not an uncommon thing, at least in America, to read/write, "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone was read to me at school today", without quotes, despite it not being perfectly correct. My point was that the post simply needs more information and cannot be accurately answered with 100% certainty without it.

Answer (score 3):

"**The minutes of the Stockholders Meeting were presented and discussed" is the correct sentence.** The subject **'minutes**' is plural, and it should take a plural verb (**were**).

> **Minutes**, also known as protocols or, informally, notes, **are** the instant written record of a meeting or hearing. **They** typically **describe** the events of the meeting and may include a list of attendees, a statement of the issues considered by the participants, and related responses or decisions for the issues".

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minutes))

> **minutes** plural noun :
>   the written record of what was said at a meeting

(from the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minutes))

Comment: 'Minutes' as used here is non-count (but _does_ take plural agreement).

Comment: CDO and other dictionaries are wrong with the 'plural noun' (which demands 'count noun') label. According to CGEL, a count noun [usage] must accept a numeral. Thus 'one minute' (singular count noun usage), '4 minutes' (plural count noun usage). However, 'The last 3 minutes have been misfiled' is unacceptable, so this is a non-count usage. Plural in form, yes. Taking a plural verb-form, yes. But not a plural noun usage. You need 'the last 3 sets of minutes have been misfiled'.

Comment: CGEL deals with grammar, and uses better analyses and terminology thereabouts than dictionaries. Not that I'm saying it's always gospel. But the primary test for countness they give is possibility of use with a numeral. *3 police were there. *3 binoculars were stolen. 3 minutes were left. *3 minutes have gone missing from the filing cabinet. / Agreement with non-count nouns is not always obvious. Statistics is my favourite subject. Measles is often dangerous. Shorts are not to be worn. Minutes are essential for legal reasons.

Comment: I've said 'minutes' is plural and it should take a plural verb. Is that right or wrong? Can you say the OP's first sentence is the right one? What about these:(The Free Dictionary) minutes pl n; minute book: a book in which minutes HAVE been written. (Collins) plural noun: 
The minutes of a meeting ARE the written records of the things that ARE discussed or decided at it.  (M-B) minutes plural :  the official record of the proceedings of a meeting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Where did you get this idea that a non-count noun cannot be a plural noun? The implication that "non-count" and "plural" must be mutually exclusive terms seems bizarre to me; if you object to this answer on that account, please back up your argument.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Rodney Huddleston's "[SHORT OVERVIEW OF ENGLISH SYNTAX](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html)" refers to "plural-only nouns" such as *belongings, clothes, genitals, scissors; cattle, police* and also mentions that "clothes" is a non-count noun. So it seems to me Huddleston does consider some words to be plural non-count nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Trousers are always spoken as if plural.

- INCORRECT:

  > I put on my gray trouser.
  >   I have your trouser.
- CORRECT:

  > I put on my gray trousers.
  >   I have your trousers.

Unlike them, the minutes of a meeting *are* a list of events, whereas the report of the minutes of a meeting *is* a [singular report of a] list of events.

(e.g.)

1. The meeting was called to order at 9:03am. The treasurer's report
   was reviewed by Treasurer Mnuchin.
2. Motion by Chao to accept the report. Support by DeVos. Approved.
3. Motion by Pence to accept the minutes of the August meeting. Support by Pompeo. Approved.

You can clarify by adding an object:

- Attached are the minutes of the meeting.
- Attached is **a copy** of the minutes of the meeting.
- The minutes are in your mailbox.
- **The report** of the minutes is in your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

"Minutes"or "issues or topics" when understood and discussed individually at a meeting, is considered plural and therefore the term takes a plural verb.

However, when "minutes' is taken to mean as a single "report", it should take a singular verb. Examples:

- The minutes/issues/topics of the previous meeting "were" discussed or deliberated upon by the members of the group.
- The Minutes of the previous meeting (Report) was approved and adopted by the group.